# "Execute decorators" phase takes forever

Tags: maven-3, sonarqube

I was just analyzing our (1 main/ 3 sub) project and wanted to analyze the code with my local Sonar server by typing `mvn sonar:sonar` (after cleaning and packaging the project(s)).

It successfully analyzes the EJB project but in the phase *Execute decorators ...* it takes forever to complete (around half an hour). This makes the analysis of the project very slow. What is going on in that phase and how can I improve the speed?

Best regards,
Sebastian

Versions used:

- Maven 3.0.3
- Sonar 2.10

Comment: Still slow in sonar 3.2.  I'm using mySQL on a nice machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this, it could be linked to using Derby, the only proposed solution is using a stronger db instead.

Following comments from sinbadblue here are links to discussions with answers from sonar team members which suggest 2 known reasons for execute decorator to be slow :

- Using derby
- Having the database server on a different network from the analyzer

Here are the links

- 2010 http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.sonar.general/4902
- 2011 http://sonar.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonar-slow-in-quot-Execute-Decorators-quot-td3187847.html
- 2012 http://sonar.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonar-analysis-remains-on-Execute-Decorators-for-Net-Applications-tp4514700p4515249.html

The database is not always the issue but these 2 should definitely be checked before further investigation.

Comment: Will mark your answer as correct, as it's very likely. Unfortunately, I can't prove this, since I'm not concerned with that project anymore.

Comment: I don't think the root cause is database. It is so easy that blaming database for slow operations. I have observed same issue with sonar install on postgresql.

Comment: In my case switching from derby to postgresql did speed things up considerably. the original answer had a link to the sonar website which seems to have disappeared :/